# Spring boot 1.5.8.RELEASE imports Java 8 compiled class

Tags: java, spring-boot, jetty, htmlunit

I don't know if I am missing something, but I have a Java 7, spring-boot project where I am trying to import and use htmlunit.
Htmlunit uses org/eclipse/jetty/websocket/api/Session and I am getting

```
java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/eclipse/jetty/websocket/api/Session : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0
```

Running `mvn dependency:tree` I could obtain the websocket version:

```
[INFO] |  +- net.sourceforge.htmlunit:htmlunit:jar:2.21:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- xalan:xalan:jar:2.5.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:jar:4.5.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:jar:4.4.8:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:jar:4.5.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- net.sourceforge.htmlunit:htmlunit-core-js:jar:2.17:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- net.sourceforge.htmlunit:neko-htmlunit:jar:2.21:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- xerces:xercesImpl:jar:2.8.1:provided
[INFO] |  |  |     \- xml-apis:xml-apis:jar:1.4.01:provided
[INFO] |  |  +- net.sourceforge.cssparser:cssparser:jar:0.9.18:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.w3c.css:sac:jar:1.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.eclipse.jetty.websocket:websocket-client:jar:9.4.7.v20170914:compile
[INFO] |  |     +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-client:jar:9.4.7.v20170914:compile
[INFO] |  |     |  \- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-http:jar:9.4.7.v20170914:compile
[INFO] |  |     +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-xml:jar:9.4.7.v20170914:compile
[INFO] |  |     +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-util:jar:9.4.7.v20170914:compile
[INFO] |  |     +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-io:jar:9.4.7.v20170914:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- org.eclipse.jetty.websocket:websocket-common:jar:9.4.7.v20170914:compile
[INFO] |  |        \- org.eclipse.jetty.websocket:websocket-api:jar:9.4.7.v20170914:compile
```

Which indeed was upgrade on 1.5.8.RELEASE of spring-boot https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/10396

So.. am I missing something? Is spring boot 1.5.8 Java 7 compatible?

EDIT: https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/issues/2151
So... should I just downgrade my spring-boot version? I can't go past Java 7 yet.

Comment: Better use java 8 or 9.

Comment: Java 10 is now out. You'll need to use another Boot version, or use Undertow or Tomcat. You might also consider filing a bug against Boot.

Comment: Spring Boot is backward compatible. In the worst case, you can use sniffer to check if there is compatibility. please check https://spring.io/blog/2015/04/03/how-spring-achieves-compatibility-with-java-6-7-and-8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two different things here: Spring Boot 1.5.x itself requires JDK7+, but this requirement can change depending on your choice of container.

Jetty 9.3+ requires JDK8, but using Jetty 9.2 should be fine with JDK7 (see the [Spring Boot 1.5.x system requirements page](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.5.8.RELEASE/reference/html/getting-started-system-requirements.html)).

Downgrading your jetty dependency by changing the `<jetty.version>` maven property should be enough.

Spring Boot builds samples applications to demonstrate compatibility - [here's one for Spring Boot 1.5.x + Jetty 9.2](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/tree/1.5.x/spring-boot-samples/spring-boot-sample-jetty92).

Comment: Jetty 9.2 is EOL (End of Life) - https://dev.eclipse.org/mhonarc/lists/jetty-dev/msg02726.html